# Python VirtualENV not working on Windows 10

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I try to create a new "virtualenv prod" it runs the below output in the cmd, and it runs for minutes with no indication that it will finish or stop. Needless to say no virtualenv gets created.
I'm using Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10, virtualenv 16.6.1. This was working at some stage not sure why it stopped working?

Output in cmd:
Running virtualenv with interpreter c:\python37\python.exe
This line gets output continuously......

Comment: I had this issue running from PowerShell Prompt. When I ran 'python -m venv ENV_NAME' from command line it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use one of the two approaches bellow when creating the virtual environment :

`python3 -m venv ENV_NAME`

or

`python3 C:\Python36\Tools\scripts\pyvenv.py ENV_NAME`

More information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: because I had the same issue and as he says "Needless to say no virtualenv gets created" , so basically he cannot create a venv, but if you run it with -m flag it should be ok: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: WORKED: python3 -m venv ENV_NAME. I also tested via Visual studio Code Terminal and  CMD, in both cases 'virtualenv prod' does not work, but in both cases 'python -m venv ENV_NAME' worked. Thanks, I'm learning python ground up so all of this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble on Windows, try this:

```
python -m venv venv

.\venv\Scripts\activate
```