# python not working in virtualenv, error: "Unable to create process"

Tags: python, pip, path, virtualenv

I have tried to make a virtual environment using virtualenv, but after activating the environment and trying to use either python or pip, I get an error like this:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Dylan Gonzalez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
```

If I type `py` instead of `python` in the command prompt, I get the same error but the path to the python executable leads to python.exe file inside of env/Scripts.

There are several methods I have tried to fix this error:

- Uninstalled all versions of Python, and installed the latest version (Python 3.10.0) for all users
- I have made sure that the Path variables are correct (at least I'm pretty sure)
- I have tried uninstalling virtualenv and re-installing it using `pip, python -m pip, pip3, py -m`
- I have upgraded my pip version
- I have tried making a virtual environment using `venv`, but when I do this, I get the following error: `Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\Dylan Gonzalez\\repos\\automated-compilations\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.` It fails to properly create the virtual environment, as the only files inside of env/Scripts are python.exe and pythonw.exe

I suspect that it might be an issue with the space - "Dylan Gonzalez" - in my file path, although I'm not sure how to set a new name.

After creating the virtual environment, when I type `where python` or `where pip`, it correctly shows a new path to the executables which are in the env/Scripts directory.

I've made sure to do my proper research before posting this question, I've been at it for hours, any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This seems to do the trickkk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56988926/10501115